# Replacing Numbers If they are a certain Worth

Tags: python, replace, numbers

I am trying to make a system where if a number is more than 5 or equal to 5 then replace that number with the number 7 and if a number is less then 5 then replace that with 2

Eg

```
Number= 93591374 
Answer= 72772272
```

I don't know how to do this exactly. Any help? Sorry new to python

Comment: You definitely confuse _digits_ (5, 7) and _numbers_ (93591374). Please update your answer to dispell the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the input as a string char by char and convert it to int after the loop process is over.

```
n = '93591374'
ret = ''

for x in n:  
    if int(x) >= 5:
        ret += '7'
    else:
        ret += '2'

ret = int(ret)
print(ret)
```

OUTPUT:

```
72772272
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 93591374

#convert number to a string
str_num = str(number)

#create a variable to hold your answer
answer = ""

#iterate over all characters in the number string
for dig in str_num:
    #typecast the dig variable into an int, so we can use a logical operator (greater than or equal to)
    if int(dig) >= 5:
       #set the answer variable value to the current value plus a new '7' digit appended at the end
       answer += "7"
    #typecast the dig variable into an int, so we can use a logical operator (less than)
    elif int(dig) < 5:
        #set the answer variable value to the current value plus a new '2' digit appended at the end
        answer += "2"
#print the resulting string of digits 
print(answer)
```